# WCF serviceCertificate - allowing alternate certificates for single service

Tags: wcf, configuration

I have a WCF service (built with VS2008, .Net 3.5) using X509 certs for both server and client. It seems to work fine. However there's a need to allow different server certs to be used by different clients. This is where I'm having the issue.

Back in the old WSE 2.0 separate-policy-file days, I could specify the server cert this way in the request policy:

```
...
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="RequestPolicy">
  <wsp:MessagePredicate wsp:Usage="wsp:Required" ...>
  ...
  <wssp:Confidentiality wsp:Usage="wsp:Required">
    <wssp:KeyInfo>
      <wssp:SecurityToken>
        <wssp:TokenType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3</wssp:TokenType>
      </wssp:SecurityToken>
    </wssp:KeyInfo>
    ...
  </wssp:Confidentiality>
</wsp:Policy>
...
```

This allowed any X509 cert known to the server to be used in the call; because the token type was supplied but no specific cert details.

I'd like to do something similar in the WCF service, but can't find a way to configure it to use "any" certificate; the configuration seems to *have* to boil down to a specific certificate:

```
...
<behavior name="NameOfServiceBehavior">
  ...
  <serviceCredentials>
    <clientCertificate>
      <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck" />
    </clientCertificate>
    <serviceCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="SubjectNameOfCertificate" />
    <issuedTokenAuthentication allowUntrustedRsaIssuers="true" />
  </serviceCredentials>
</behavior>
...
```

I can't find a way to have multiple behaviours for one service, or multiple certificates for one behaviour.

The client certs don't have to be specified, so I'd hope there is a way to be similarly "generic" with the server certificate. I'd prefer to keep all the WCF "stuff" in the configuration, and avoid coding custom handlers for the security.

Thanks,